# C# check xml node the safe way?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the code:

```
if (Element.SelectSingleNode("/rsp/merged_poco/organizations/organization/name") != null)
                this.Organization = Element.SelectSingleNode("/rsp/merged_poco/organizations/organization/name").InnerText;
```

However there is a changes that "merged_poco" may not have "organizations". Would my code result in an error? Or just that null check suffice?
In my null check should I also check to see if "organizations" and "organization" exist?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should suffice. You can also optimize it as the following:

```
XmlNode node = Element.SelectSingleNode("/rsp/merged_poco/organizations/organization/name");
if (node != null)
    this.Organization = node.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how exactly does a certain method behave, you should read [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.Xml.XmlNode`
>   The first `XmlNode` that matches the XPath query or `null` if no matching node is found.